# Run Jitsi SIP communicator in eclipse

Tags: java, ant, voip, sip-server, jitsi

I am using Jitsi in my application for chat.I downloaded Jitsi source code through SVN into my eclipse.I have to build this project with Ant and start working.I executed the build.xml using Ant and the build was successful.But when i run the project as Java Application lot of exceptions are thrown.

```
Auto-properties install: reference:file:sc-bundles/plugin-msofficecomm.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: reference:file:sc-bundles/plugin-msofficecomm.jar - java.io.IOException: Referenced file does not exist: sc-bundles\plugin-msofficecomm.jar)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: reference:file:sc-bundles/plugin-msofficecomm.jar
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2545)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2501)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:150)
    at org.apache.felix.main.AutoProcessor.processAutoProperties(AutoProcessor.java:296)
    at org.apache.felix.main.AutoProcessor.process(AutoProcessor.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.main.Main.main(Main.java:291)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.launcher.SIPCommunicator.main(SIPCommunicator.java:153)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Referenced file does not exist: sc-bundles\plugin-msofficecomm.jar
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.createRevisionFromLocation(BundleArchive.java:842)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.reviseInternal(BundleArchive.java:549)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.<init>(BundleArchive.java:148)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.create(BundleCache.java:251)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2541)
```

I have only some part of the exceptions.It says that some reference files are missing.
I have run the application and start making changes in it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue while using netbeans IDE.  Add "sc-bundle" directory to source path. that should resolve the bundle issues